# XMPP: AngularJs + Strophe.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmpp, strophe

I have a basic XMPP client working on strophe.js.

On login I create handlers such as

```
connect = new Strophe.Connection('http://localhost/http-bind');
...
...

    connect.addHandler(on_message, null, "message", "chat");
    connect.addHandler(on_presence, null, "presence");

...
...
```

and then I "listen" to those

```
function on_presence(presence) {
// handling presence
}

function on_message(presence) {
// handling presence
}
```

So I am trying to "convert" it into AngularJS. The first part is pretty straight forward. I have a controller which handles the login part just fine:

```
angular.module('app').controller('loginCtrl', function($scope) {
connect = new Strophe.Connection('http://website.com/http-bind');

connect.connect(data.jid, data.password, function (status) {
  if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
    connect.addHandler(on_message, null, "message", "chat");
    connect.addHandler(on_presence, null, "presence");
  }
}
})
```

But how do I actually begin listening to those events (on_message, on_presence) in the context of angular across all the controllers I have.

Comment: Hi, I am working on a similar such problem. Were you able to make this work and How? 

Have you considered Socket.io instead of Strophe.js as Socket.io  have angular wrappers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested above (or bellow) I wrapped strophe in a service so my login "mechanism" looks like this:

```
.controller('loginCtrl', function(xmppAuth) {

    xmppAuth.auth(login, password);

})
```

any my service:

```
.service('xmppAuth', function() {

return {

auth: function(login, password) {
   connect = new Strophe.Connection('http://mydomain.net/http-bind');
   connect.connect(login, password, function (status) {
       if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
           // we are in, addHandlers and stuff
       }
   }
}

}

})
```

Answer (score 7):

Wrap Strophe in an [Angular Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services). Angular Services are meant to be use as singletons, so you will be able to instantiate the Strophe Service once, and use it everywhere (using Dependency Injection).

Answer (score 0):

Or may be you can create a module for Strophe and then include the module in your app, and then include strophe as a variable where ever you want to use it.