# XMPP: AngularJS + Strophe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmpp, strophe

The basic XMPP with strophe and javascript wants to convert to AngularJS.

```
.controller('loginCtrl', function(xmppAuth) {

    xmppAuth.auth(login, password);

})
```

and in service:

```
    .service('xmppAuth', function() {

.return {

    auth: function(login, password) {
       connect = new Strophe.Connection(domain);
       connect.connect(login, password, function (status) {
           if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
               connect.addHandler(on_roster_changed,"jabber:iq:roster", "iq", "set");
               connect.addHandler(on_iq, null, "iq","");
               connect.addHandler(on_presence, null, "presence");
               connect.addHandler(on_message, null, 'message', '');
           }
       }
    }

    }

})
```

in js file

```
var on_presence = function(presence){
    code
}
```

when i run this there is no error. But all handling events like on_presence() method called only once. this is handler event of Strophe Connection object. Is there is any remain in this code or what should i do for handling strophes event with angularJS?

I refered [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337123/xmpp-angularjs-strophe-js) but it not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the Strophe.js docs for addHandler](http://strophe.im/strophejs/doc/1.1.3/files/strophe-js.html#Strophe.Connection.addHandler):

> The handler should return true if it is to be invoked again; returning false will remove the handler after it returns.

Therefore, your on_presence code should return true if you want it to be invoked again:

```
var on_presence = function(presence) {
    // do some stuff
    return true;
};
```

Comment: Yeah well, as said in the mailinglist: The docs aren't highlighting this fact good enough. Many Strophe.js users made this mistake initially as well, including me. I added now a PR to improve the docs: https://github.com/strophe/strophejs/pull/86